# PHP class returning properties that can be iterated?

Tags: php, mysql

My apologies, I'm a novice at best when it comes to PHP so please be gentle.

I have created a class that will grab some information from a database and return the various values as properties of the class. Which works great as I only ask for one row.

Like so:

```
$mydata = new mydataclass;

$mydata->getaparticularrowofdata($uniqueid);

$value1 = $mydata->variable1;
$value2 = $mydata->variable2;
$value3 = $mydata->variable3;
```

I would like to do something like:

```
$mydata = new mydataclass;

$mydata->getafewrowsofdata($somefieldvaluetomatch);

if ($mydata->count != 0) {

// some sort of loop to iterate through each row until at the end, each time replacing       the property values with the new data

echo $mydata->variable1;
echo $mydata->variable2;
echo $mydata->variable3;

//

}
```

This is just an example obviously. Hope I'm making sense.

Is this doable? If so some example code would be most appreciated :)

The answer may be very simple but for some reason I can't seem to wrap my head around it this evening.

Many thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you actually want. Also, why echo your data? Echo sends text to the browser. That's all it does. And you say you want to replace the values. You mean in your database? In the script on runtime? Or in the browser? Non of this is clear to me.

Comment: The php manual has some nice examples on the iterator interface - read through the code and see if you have any more questions.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php

Answer (score 0):

It will depend somewhat on the format of the result set you're returning, but here are some examples of how you could iterate through a result set, using your example.

If you return the result set as an object:

```
  $resultsObject = $mydata->getafewrowsofdata($somefieldvaluetomatch);

  foreach($resultsObject as $result)
  {
    echo $result->variable1;
    echo $result->variable2;
    echo $result->variable3;
  }
```

If you return the result set as an array:

```
  $resultsArray = $mydata->getafewrowsofdata($somefieldvaluetomatch);

  foreach($resultsArray as $result)
  {
    echo $result['variable1'];
    echo $result['variable2'];
    echo $result['variable3'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modifying the properties of `mydataclass` when you retrieve data and subsequently iterate through the data (that's a lot of side effects, and you wouldn't be able to use your class to select multiple sets of data concurrently), I'd recommend having your `getafewrowsofdata` method return either an array of data (one element per row) or returning a result object that implements the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface.

If you're using PDO, an easy way to accomplish this would be to have your `getafewrowsofdata` function use the [`fetchAll`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method of PDO. This can even return objects of a custom class (see example 4).